# "'pub get' has not been run" not resolving - Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

I am new on flutter, I see this error on top in android studio

[image]

I clicked "get dependencies" and "upgrade dependencies" but it did not work, then I clicked "Ignore" and then it went but it comes back when android studio restarted or open a new project.

Does anyone know how to solve it !!!

I clicked "get dependencies" and "upgrade dependencies" but it did not work, then I clicked "Ignore" and then it went but it comes back when android studio restarted or open a new project.

Comment: When you restart the Android Studio or when there are changes in pubspec.yaml file, you would get the prompt to run "flutter pub get" command. Just run it once and see if the pub get is run successfully. if yes then ignore the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This is a knowing issue in the IntelliJ

Just run it manually in the app/module package level terminal command

```
flutter pub get
```

and this error will gone.

**UPDATE**
Click on the terminal on the left-bottom side of IDE
[image]

By default it should open the `Terminal` in your project root directory `list_in_flutter` and type the command above and press `Enter`
[image]

Comment: I am using android studio.

Comment: Issue the same for IntelliJ IDE as well as for Android Studio

Comment: ok, where is "app/module package level terminal command"?? @powerman23rus

Comment: still does not works... :(